# SharePoint Tabs - Parent/Child Integraty?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, web-part

I need to develop a SharePoint 2010 application which will be having more than 120 Fields.

I would like to break the Fields into smaller modules (i.e., Summary, Impact, Dependencies, Plan, Decision, Closure, Documents) and thought of creating Lists to store the details separately.

Now, how do I ensure the referential integrity is maintained? means that, how do I maintain/pass the primary key value across the different tabs? what kind of webpart I can use?

or it is better to develop a classic aspx application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to establish what the base point of entry will be so that all of your separate lists will have something to look up to.

This can live as a single form, but you'd need to submit the information to your master list first, get the list item id it generates and then split off the other segments in separate calls so you can set a lookup column to the created master item.

On display and edit forms, you'll need to use a data source that links all the lists together so you can render the sections as appropriate.

Mark Rackley has a few blog posts on creating parent/child relationships that might be of some use.
http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4